# Mass user authentication for a bracket system

Tags: authentication, templates

I'm currently setting up a layout for a website that's going to be a sort of "bracket" website, where users can sign up and they can be approved/denied by an administrator. I'm currently at a roadblock in my design process, because I can't figure out an appropriate way to handle mass user authentication.

For example, there will be bracket that any person who has registered on the website will be able to sign up for. When they sign up, they're put into a "waiting pool", where they're sorted by a system that puts them into four or five different skill groups (as to not match the best players against the worst). After everything is sorted, the people in the pool need to be "approved" for the tournament, which is where I'm having trouble.

If I have 100 people in this pool, what would be the most efficient way to display them for approval (this would only be done by an administrator on the back-end of the website)? I was thinking of listing them and having check boxes next to each person's username, but it seems like that would be tedious and time consuming. Is there any other way to handle this issue?

Comment: What does the administrator need to know about each person when approving them? I'm wondering what information needs to be displayed in the approval interface.

Comment: From what I can tell right now, it would probably display something like: `Username | SkillGroup | T.Entered`, where the username would be a link to the respective profile, and T.Entered would be the tournaments entered so far.
edit: I misunderstood. The administrators will be approving/denying users based on their preferences, some tournaments might not be appropriate for some users, but there's a good possibility they might sign up for it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to the solution I would suggest for this.

I would firstly want to filter the list of people based on my criteria. So if I only want to approve people in the "intermediate" skill group (I don't know what the real groups are) who have also entered between 5 and 10 tournaments, I could filter the list to show only those people. Equally, if I know I want to reject beginners, I could filter the list to show only those people and then easily reject them.

Listing the people with checkboxes, as you mentioned, does seem sensible to me. That means I can select multiple people and then approve or reject them in a single action. I would include a single checkbox at the top that allows me to easily select all.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm82TB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This is an awesome idea! I shared this with my administrators and they really liked the layout of this, so I guess this is what we're going to do. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Good stuff. Happy to help.